# R: using foreach() with sample() procedures in randomForest() call

Tags: r, foreach, parallel-processing, random-forest

I have a large dataframe (~700 n x 36000 p) and plan to conduct randomForest analyses in R. Due to the runtime burdens of sending the full frame to randomForest (even with parallel computing and 512 GB RAM), I would like to send different random subsamples of the dataframe (~5% p) to randomForest in many independent runs (Nruns).  For smaller dataframes, I have created a foreach loop to send the entire dataframe to randomForest and return a matrix of importance results that is dim(p,Nruns) plus 3 additional rows containing some additional information generated in each Nrun. However, I am having trouble constructing the foreach() component of the script to send a different subsample of the dataframe to randomForest for each run.  (The subsampling consists of two steps: Create a balanced dataset (on outcome class) by sampling rows first (this part works), then select a subset of columns.) The desired results would still be a dataframe of dim(p+3, Nruns) but each column would contain results only for the variables that were randomly-selected in the run represented by that column (i.e., there would be missing values for the variables not selected for that run).  When I submit the code below (using the fake data created below), I get the following error:
"error calling combine function:
"
Note, as indicated in the code, if I exclude the step where random columns are selected, but retain the step where the balancing is done, I do not get an error and the output is as expected (with dim(p+3,Nruns) and all cells have non-zero values.) So, the problem is in the section of code where the column sampling is done.
I would like to know if anyone can suggest a remedy to the below code that will do a new random subsampling of columns (and rows) for each of 1:Nruns.

Thanks for any suggestions.

```
##########################################################################
# CREATE FAKE DATA
##########################################################################
FAKEinput <- 
data.frame(A=sample(25:75,20, replace=T), B=sample(1:2,20,replace=T), C=as.factor(sample(0:1,20,replace=T,prob=c(0.3,0.7))),
    D=sample(200:350,20,replace=T), E=sample(2300:2500,20,replace=T), F=sample(92000:105000,20,replace=T),
    G=sample(280:475,20,replace=T),H=sample(470:550,20,replace=T),I=sample(2537:2723,20,replace=T),
    J=sample(2984:4199,20,replace=T),K=sample(222:301,20,replace=T),L=sample(28:53,20,replace=T),
    M=sample(3:9,20,replace=T),N=sample(0:2,20,replace=T),O=sample(0:5,20,replace=T),P=sample(0:2,20,replace=T),
    Q=sample(0:2,20,replace=T), R=sample(0:2,20,replace=T), S=sample(0:7,20,replace=T))

##########################################################################
# set FOREST DATASET
##########################################################################
forestData <- FAKEinput

##########################################################################
# set Outcome 
##########################################################################
Outcome <- "C"

##########################################################################
#  set DV
#########################################################################
forestDV <- forestData$C
str(forestDV) #factor

##########################################################################
#set up number of runs:
##########################################################################
Nruns<-5

##########################################################################
#set up ntree
##########################################################################
ntree=100

###########################################################################
#set up mtry:
###########################################################################
mtry=round(sqrt(ncol(forestData)))  #4

###########################################################################
## CREATE DATASET WITH ONLY THE PREDICTORS (I.E., OMIT OUTCOME).
###########################################################################
dropVars <- names(forestData) %in% c(Outcome)
forestPREDICTORS <- forestData[!dropVars] 

###########################################################################
#set seed first to replicate the random draw of seeds
###########################################################################
set.seed(3456)

###########################################################################
# GENERATE Nruns RANDOMSEEDS
###########################################################################
randomseed<- sample(1:(length(forestData[,1])),Nruns, replace=TRUE) #16 16 18 8 11

##########################################
#Load necessary packages into R's memory
##########################################
require(iterators)
require(foreach)
require(parallel)
require(doParallel)
require(randomForest)

###########################################
# Get the number of available logical cores
###########################################
cores <- detectCores()
cores

###########################################
# Print info on computer, OS, cores
###########################################
print(paste('Processor: ', Sys.getenv('PROCESSOR_IDENTIFIER')), sep='')
print(paste('OS: ', Sys.getenv('OS')), sep='')
print(paste('Cores: ', cores, sep=''))

##################################################################################################
#  Set up new function, called ’ImpOOBerr':
# 1 )write in the set random seed part that uses the same ‘i’ from the ‘foreach’ loops 
# 2) save the importance and summary measures output from the random forest run
# 3) combine all of the importance scores and OOB error summary results (as columns) into single matrix
# * other options tried to correct error commented out.
###################################################################################################
ImpOOBerr<-function(y,d) { 
set.seed(randomseed[i])
out.model<-randomForest(y ~ ., 
    data=d, 
    ntree=ntree,
    mtry=mtry,
    nodesize=0.1*nrow(forestData),
    importance=TRUE,
    proximity=FALSE)
# create the frame before filling with values?
#out<-data.frame(matrix(nrow=ncol(forestPREDICTORS)+3, ncol=Nruns))
out<-rbind(importance(out.model, type=1, scale=FALSE),
    mean(out.model$err.rate[,1]),
    rbind(t(t(quantile(out.model$err.rate[,1], probs=c(0.025, 0.975))))))
#rownames(out) <- c(names(forestPREDICTORS),'meanOOB','oobL95CI', 'oobU95CI') # name all the rows
# OR name only newly-added rows since randomForest importance output preserves the variable names
rownames(out)[(nrow(out)-2):nrow(out)]<-c('meanOOB','oobL95CI', 'oobU95CI') 
return(out)
}

###########################################################################
# SET UP THE CLUSTER
###########################################################################
#Setup clusters via parallel/DoParallel
cl.spec <- rep("localhost", 10)
cl <- makeCluster(cl.spec, type="SOCK")
registerDoParallel(cl, cores=10)

###########################################################################
# Employ foreach to carry out randomForest in parallel
##########################################################################
system.time(fakeRF <- foreach(i=1:Nruns, .combine='cbind', .packages='randomForest') 
    %dopar% {    #<<change to %do% to see speed difference

######################################################################################################
# FIRST, BALANCE THE DATASET ON OUTCOME CLASS FOR INPUT TO randomForest CLASSIFICATION
######################################################################################################
dat1<-forestData[forestData$C==1,]
dat0<-forestData[forestData$C==0,]

####################################################
# RESET the seed to make sure it is updating and 
# giving different samples for each run
####################################################
set.seed(randomseed[i])

####################################################
# OVERSAMPLE FROM SMALLER GROUP TO BALANCE DATASET
####################################################
rands=sample(1:dim(dat0)[1],dim(dat1)[1], replace=TRUE) 
balancedCLASS<-rbind(dat0[rands,],dat1) 

######################################################################################################
# NOW DO RANDOM SAMPLES OF THE COLUMNS (VARIABLES) TO CREATE NEW DATA SUBSETS TO SEND TO randomForest
# AT EACH RUN
# NOTE: TO TEST SCRIPT WITHOUT COLUMN SAMPLING, COMMENT OUT ALL SCRIPT BETWEEN TWO "#xxxxxxxxx.." ROWS
# AND UNCOMMENT THE NEXT THREE LINES
######################################################################################################
#forestData<-balancedCLASS
#forestDV<-balancedCLASS$C
#forestPREDICTORS <- balancedCLASS[!names(balancedCLASS) %in% c('C')]

##xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx
##xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx
####################################################
# PULL OUT PREDICTORS (i.e., exclue the outcome) 
# before sampling the columns
####################################################
PREDICTORS <- balancedCLASS[!names(balancedCLASS) %in% c('C')]

####################################################
# from the row-balanced set created above, 
# draw a 5-column subset for each run
####################################################
randsCOL= sample(1:dim(PREDICTORS)[2], 5, replace=FALSE) 

####################################################
# BIND OUTCOME VAR BACK ONTO RANDOM COL SET
####################################################
Set_BALrandsCOL <- cbind(balancedCLASS$C, balancedCLASS[,randsCOL]) 

####################################################
# FIX OUTCOME NAME (was retained as "balancedCLASS$C")
####################################################
names(Set_BALrandsCOL)[names(Set_BALrandsCOL)=="balancedCLASS$C"] <- "C"

####################################################
# ASSIGN THE OUTCOME OF SAMPLING BACK TO 
# forestData, forestDV and forestPREDICTORS for RF runs
####################################################
forestData<-Set_BALrandsCOL
forestDV<-Set_BALrandsCOL$C
forestPREDICTORS <- Set_BALrandsCOL[!names(Set_BALrandsCOL) %in% c('C')]
##xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx
##xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx

#############################################################################################
# CALL FUNCTION THAT WILL RUN randomForest AND COMBINE THE OUTPUT FROM EACH RUN
#############################################################################################
ImpOOBerr(forestDV, forestPREDICTORS)
})

##########################
# stop the cluster
##########################
stopCluster(cl)

#############################################################################################
# SAVE THE OUTPUT TO FILE
#############################################################################################
save(fakeRF, file="D:/RF/WORKING/fakeRF.rda")
```

Comment: Just trying this manually with `i=1` I get a matrix of dim(8,1) while `i=2` gives dim(7,1). If this is a known variation in the output of `ImpOOBerr` then you need a different combiner, since `cbind` will require the same number of rows.

Comment: Thanks for your response. ImpOOBerr() should produce matrices of the same size and does if I exclude script portion that takes random samples of cols (i.e., portion between "#xxxx" lines). My intention in random col selection was to select the same number of cols in each independent run. Since #col selected dictates the #rows in output matrix, each run should produce a matrix of the same size. But, since it's random sampling, the particular cols selected will differ across runs. Is error because the row.names for the matrices being combined by ImpOOBerr are different for each run? Suggestions?

Comment: Random col subsetting script now fixed so each run produces same #rows in output matrix and full code runs w/o errors. However, results are incorrect because the output matrix has 5 rows (#var drawn per run) rather than >5 expected. e.g., for 3 runs with the following random draws: run1: A,B,C,D,E; run2: B,C,E,F,G; run3: E,A,C,H,K, the output matrix would be 12 rows (A,B,C,D,E,F,G,H,K + 3 rows of summary values produced in each run) X 3 (#runs).  Do I need a function other than 'cbind' because the row.names of the matrix produced from each run are not the same?

Comment: I suggest you edit your question to include the corrected code. However, when using `cbind` on matrices that have row names, I believe the row names of the second (and subsequent) matrices are ignored/discarded silently.

Answer (score 0):

I have solved the above problem. The first comment from r2evans, allowed me to fix the 
random column subsetting section. Then, I made some modifications to the ImpOOBerr function to force the output of the function to have the same number of observations (and same row.names) in each run.  This allowed the cbind to work in the %dopar% statement.
Thanks for the feedback and suggestions.

```
##########################################################################
# CREATE FAKE DATA
##########################################################################
FAKEinput <- 
data.frame(A=sample(25:75,20, replace=T), B=sample(1:2,20,replace=T), C=as.factor(sample(0:1,20,replace=T,prob=c(0.3,0.7))),
    D=sample(200:350,20,replace=T), E=sample(2300:2500,20,replace=T), F=sample(92000:105000,20,replace=T),
    G=sample(280:475,20,replace=T),H=sample(470:550,20,replace=T),I=sample(2537:2723,20,replace=T),
    J=sample(2984:4199,20,replace=T),K=sample(222:301,20,replace=T),L=sample(28:53,20,replace=T),
    M=sample(3:9,20,replace=T),N=sample(0:2,20,replace=T),O=sample(0:5,20,replace=T),P=sample(0:2,20,replace=T),
    Q=sample(0:2,20,replace=T), R=sample(0:2,20,replace=T), S=sample(0:7,20,replace=T))

##########################################################################
# set FOREST DATASET
##########################################################################
forestData0 <- FAKEinput

##########################################################################
# set Outcome 
##########################################################################
Outcome <- "C"

##########################################################################
#  set DV
#########################################################################
forestDV0 <- forestData0$C

##########################################################################
#set up number of runs:
##########################################################################
Nruns<-5

##########################################################################
#set up ntree
##########################################################################
ntree=100

###########################################################################
## CREATE DATASET WITH ONLY THE PREDICTORS (I.E., OMIT OUTCOME).
###########################################################################
dropVars <- names(forestData0) %in% c(Outcome)
forestPREDICTORS0 <- forestData0[!dropVars] 

###########################################################################
# CREATE single-column dataframe, whichi will be used to send the
# FULL SET OF PREDICTORS TO ImpOOBerr() OUTPUT MATRIX
# Automatically-generated column name is unwieldy; change that to Predictor.
###########################################################################
VARS <-data.frame(c(names(forestPREDICTORS0),'ZZZmeanOOB','ZZZoobL95CI', 'ZZZoobU95CI'))
VARS <- rename(VARS, c(c.names.forestPREDICTORS0....ZZZmeanOOB....ZZZoobL95CI....ZZZoobU95CI..="Predictor"))
row.names(VARS) <- VARS$Predictor

###########################################################################
#set seed first to replicate the random draw of seeds
###########################################################################
set.seed(3456)

###########################################################################
# GENERATE Nruns RANDOMSEEDS
###########################################################################
randomseed<- sample(1:Nruns,Nruns, replace=FALSE) 

##########################################
#Load necessary packages into R's memory
##########################################
require(iterators)
require(foreach)
require(parallel)
require(doParallel)
require(randomForest)

###########################################
# Get the number of available logical cores
###########################################
cores <- detectCores()
cores

###########################################
# Print info on computer, OS, cores
###########################################
print(paste('Processor: ', Sys.getenv('PROCESSOR_IDENTIFIER')), sep='')
print(paste('OS: ', Sys.getenv('OS')), sep='')
print(paste('Cores: ', cores, sep=''))

##################################################################################################
# SET UP NEW FUNCTION, called ’ImpOOBerr':
# 1) write in the set random seed part that uses the same ‘i’ from the ‘foreach’ loops 
# 2) save the importance and summary measures output from the random forest run
# 3) combine all of the importance scores and OOB error summary results (as columns) into single matrix
# 4) merge the ANNOTS dataset with each 'out' file so that cbind function will work 
# (requires same # of rows and same row.names)
###################################################################################################
ImpOOBerr<-function(y,d) { 
set.seed(randomseed[i])
out.model<-randomForest(y ~ ., 
    data=d, 
    ntree=ntree,
    mtry=mtry,
    nodesize=0.1*nrow(forestData),
    importance=TRUE,
    proximity=FALSE)
out<-rbind(importance(out.model, type=1, scale=FALSE),
    mean(out.model$err.rate[,1]),
    rbind(t(t(quantile(out.model$err.rate[,1], probs=c(0.025, 0.975))))))
rownames(out)[(nrow(out)-2):nrow(out)]<-c('ZZZmeanOOB','ZZZoobL95CI', 'ZZZoobU95CI') 
out2<- merge(ANNOTS, out, by="row.names", all.x=TRUE)
row.names(out2) <- out2$Row.names
out2 <- out2[,-1]
out2 <- out2[order(row.names(out2)),]
out3 <- data.frame(out2[,-1,drop=FALSE]) # !!!! THIS WORKS !!!
return(out3)
}

###########################################################################
# SET UP THE CLUSTER
###########################################################################
#Setup clusters via parallel/DoParallel
cl.spec <- rep("localhost", 30)
cl <- makeCluster(cl.spec, type="SOCK")
registerDoParallel(cl, cores=30)

###########################################################################
# Employ foreach to carry out randomForest in parallel
##########################################################################
system.time(fakeRF <- foreach(i=1:Nruns, .combine='cbind', .packages='randomForest') 
    %dopar% {    #<<change to %do% to see speed difference

######################################################################################################
# FIRST, BALANCE THE DATASET ON OUTCOME CLASS FOR INPUT TO randomForest CLASSIFICATION
######################################################################################################
dat1<-forestData[forestData$C==1,]
dat0<-forestData[forestData$C==0,]

####################################################
# RESET the seed to make sure it is updating and 
# giving different samples for each run
####################################################
set.seed(randomseed[i])

####################################################
# OVERSAMPLE FROM SMALLER GROUP TO BALANCE DATASET
####################################################
rands=sample(1:dim(dat0)[1],dim(dat1)[1], replace=TRUE) 
balancedCLASS<-rbind(dat0[rands,],dat1) 

######################################################################################################
# SELECT RANDOM SAMPLES OF THE COLUMNS (VARIABLES) TO CREATE NEW DATA SUBSETS TO SEND TO randomForest
# AT EACH RUN
######################################################################################################

#################################################################
# FROM ROW-BALANCED SET CREATED ABOVE (balancedCLASS),
# DRAW A 5% COL (5% OF 35365=1768) SUBSET FOR EACH RUN
# OMIT THE OUTCOME COLUMN (3) FROM THE RANDOM SELECTION
#################################################################
randsCOLs= sample(balancedCLASS[,-c(3)], 5, replace=FALSE) 

####################################################
# BIND OUTCOME VAR BACK ONTO RANDOM COL SET
####################################################
Set_BALrandsCOL <- cbind(balancedCLASS$C, randsCOLs) 

####################################################
# FIX OUTCOME NAME (was retained as "balancedCLASS$C")
####################################################
names(Set_BALrandsCOL)[names(Set_BALrandsCOL)=="balancedCLASS$C"] <- "C"

####################################################
# ASSIGN THE OUTCOME OF SAMPLING BACK TO 
# forestData, forestDV and forestPREDICTORS for RF runs
####################################################
forestData<-Set_BALrandsCOL
forestDV<-Set_BALrandsCOL$C
forestPREDICTORS <- Set_BALrandsCOL[!names(Set_BALrandsCOL) %in% c('C')]

#############################################################################################
# CALL FUNCTION THAT WILL RUN randomForest AND COMBINE THE OUTPUT FROM EACH RUN
#############################################################################################
ImpOOBerr(forestDV, forestPREDICTORS)
})

##########################
# stop the cluster
##########################
stopCluster(cl)

#############################################################################################
# SAVE THE OUTPUT TO FILE
#############################################################################################
save(fakeRF, file="D:/LearningMachines/RF/Knight_ADNI/WORKING/fakeRF.rda")
```